# How to show first li after last li with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove first li and add that after last li using jQuery. Here is my html code.

```
<ul id="client_list">
    <li id="1"><img src="img/client.png"/>1</li>
    <li id="2"><img src="img/client1.png"/>2</li>
    <li id="3"><img src="img/client2.png"/>3</li>
    <li id="4"><img src="img/client3.png"/>4</li>
    <li id="5"><img src="img/client4.png"/>5</li>
    <li id="6"><img src="img/client5.png"/>6</li>
    <li id="7"><img src="img/client6.png"/>7</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to do with jQuery `hide()` and `show()` methods? Any help highly appriciate.

Comment: *Is it possible to do with jQuery hide() and show() methods?* - Is *Yes* an sufficient answer to your question?

Comment: @PranavCBalan Can you tell me how to do that? I'm trying to make a logo slider to run auto and need to move slider to one direction. For that i need to do that part.

Comment: @KilianStinson Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: After you tried it yourself I could give you hints on what's wrong with your code. Rory McCrossan already answered your question. I myself don't answer `how to do this` questions without any research effort.

Comment: @KilianStinson Yes that's work for me. Thumbs up!

Comment: @KilianStinson me either usually, however new guidelines from on high seem to be pushing people to answer the 'how do I do this' with no effort questions instead of DV and closing them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `insertAfter()` along with `:first` and `:last`. You can use the `id` attributes to select the elements if you want, but that will make your code more brittle.

```js
$('li:first').insertAfter('li:last');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="client_list">
  <li id="1"><img src="img/client.png"/>1</li>
  <li id="2"><img src="img/client1.png"/>2</li>
  <li id="3"><img src="img/client2.png"/>3</li>
  <li id="4"><img src="img/client3.png"/>4</li>
  <li id="5"><img src="img/client4.png"/>5</li>
  <li id="6"><img src="img/client5.png"/>6</li>
  <li id="7"><img src="img/client6.png"/>7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this, with the following approach.

```js
var firstLI = $("#client_list li").first();
$("#client_list").append(firstLI);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="client_list">
    <li id="1"><img src="img/client.png"/>1</li>
    <li id="2"><img src="img/client1.png"/>2</li>
    <li id="3"><img src="img/client2.png"/>3</li>
    <li id="4"><img src="img/client3.png"/>4</li>
    <li id="5"><img src="img/client4.png"/>5</li>
    <li id="6"><img src="img/client5.png"/>6</li>
    <li id="7"><img src="img/client6.png"/>7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eq()` in `jquery` also. But @Rory has suggested a much simple approach. But `eq()` can find any position in you list.

> eq() method providing 0-based position.

```js
$('#client_list').find('li').eq(0).insertAfter('#client_list>li:last');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="client_list">
  <li id="1"><img src="img/client.png"/>1</li>
  <li id="2"><img src="img/client1.png"/>2</li>
  <li id="3"><img src="img/client2.png"/>3</li>
  <li id="4"><img src="img/client3.png"/>4</li>
  <li id="5"><img src="img/client4.png"/>5</li>
  <li id="6"><img src="img/client5.png"/>6</li>
  <li id="7"><img src="img/client6.png"/>7</li>
</ul>
```